# Rails - passing session info in hidden fields - getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, hidden-field

I'm trying to pass a project id from a session in a hidden field on a task form, so that when the task is created, it has the id of the project that it is assigned to. I've done this before fine, and have even tried copying over the code that I used from when it worked, but changing names and I'm getting errors no matter what I do - if anyone could help point out where I'm going wrong, it would be much appreciated, thanks!

The error I'm getting with this configuration is: "unknown attribute: project_id"

View Code (tasks/_form):

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => session[:project_id] %>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

Model Code (task):

```
attr_accessible :project_id

belongs_to :project
```

Controller code (tasks_controller):

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
  @project_id = session[:project_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @task }
  end
end

def create
  project_id = session[:project_id]
  @task = Task.new(params[:task])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the application trace - it is pointing to line 46, which in my code is the '@task = Task.new(params[:task])' line in the create action...?

```
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:46:in `new'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

Comment: A stack trace would be nice, so people would know where this error comes from. I'm guessing it's from `@task = Task.new(params[:task])` but it would be nice to if you could confirm that.

Comment: Ok - I've added the application trace to the question.

Comment: You're right about the line it is throwing the error for - any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use project_id as a hidden field and in your controller actions?

Comment: I wasn't sure which I needed to place it in - I was using a code template from a tutorial I followed a while ago and that's how they did it. I thought that if you used a hidden_field as opposed to hidden_field_tag, you needed to place the info in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Task model have a `project_id` column?

Comment: Ah yes, whoops! - I've just checked on the actual database and it doesn't - I was accidentally using an old version of the project model that doesn't have the has_many associations set up for tasks. I've added these, and saved, restarted the server, done rake db:migrate etc - but how do I get the db to add the column itself so that it links properly as a foreign key? Or is it ok to add it manually? Thanks!

Comment: It's still giving me the same error even though I have added the correct associations in the models now. Any idea why?

Comment: I've fixed it - I had to add a new migration with the appropriate foreign keys - if anyone else is reading this and has a similar problem, I found the answer here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html in section 3.3.1 about adding foreign keys. Thanks for everyone's help!